# Find partial matching strings between two vectors in R

Tags: r

I am working with two string vectors in R.

The first one, *proprietor*, contains about 100,000 elements and looks like:

```
> proprietor
 [1] "GERALD RICA LIMITED"                                             
 [2] "EUROMASTER STUDIO SRL"                                           
 [3] "CENTRE D'ECHANGES INTERNATIONAUX (CEI)"                          
 [4] "RONTEC SERVICE STATION 1A LIMITED"                               
 [5] "MOORGARTH PROPERTIES (LUXEMBOURG) S.A.R.L"                       
 [6] "BEAVRON INVESTMENTS LIMITED"                                     
 [7] "MITRALI LIMITED"
```

The other one, *name*, contains about 700,000 similar elements :

```
> name 
 [1] "MULTIPOINT HOLDINGS LIMITED"                                     
 [2] "NYASA PROPERTY LIMITED"                                          
 [3] "WHITE LODGE HOLDINGS LIMITED"                                    
 [4] "MULTIPOINT HOLDINGS LIMITED"                                     
 [5] "MULTIPOINT HOLDINGS LIMITED"                                     
 [6] "JBL INVESTMENT LIMITED"                                          
 [7] "DIMBLEBY LIMITED"                                                
 [8] "LIDL U.K. GMBH"
```

I would like to know which elements of *proprietor* are also in *name*, taking into account that there could be some typos or that some words like "LIMITED" can also be written down "LTD" for example.

**What I have already tried:**

- `proprietor %in% name` returns an empty element, which I know is not the case
- `intersect(proprietor, name)` is not working because there are duplicates in my vectors
- mainly, I've tried to do a loop with `agrep()` to allow for partial matches:

```
    for (i in 1:97034) {
      if (is.null(agrep(proprietor[i], name, max.distance=0.1, value=TRUE, useBytes=TRUE, costs=NULL, ignore.case=TRUE))=="TRUE") {
        test[i] <- 1
      } else {
        test[i] <- agrep(proprietor[i], name, max.distance=0.1, value=TRUE, useBytes=TRUE, costs=NULL, ignore.case=TRUE)
      }
    }
```

It returns the error "regcomp error:  'Out of memory'". I am beginning in R so 1) I can see this loop is not the easiest way to do it 2) I didn't get how to correct this out of memory error.

- I also tried the solution given in this post: [Find matching strings between two vectors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371321/find-matching-strings-between-two-vectors-in-r) but I couldn't implement it (error message: Error: assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634. I couldn't find where it was coming from.)

Any suggestion on how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the function `adist` from the package `stringdist`.

Minimal working example:

Create a vector of non-sense words and call the vector a:

`a <- c("gkhk", "ololsol", "tyuil", "tyuio", "etytyuli")`

Modify some of the words (with more or less degree of modification) and call that vector b:

`b <- c("gwrwkhk", "olseotyuioplsol", "thsyuil", "tasyuio", "etytyuli")`

Then calculate the distance between the elements

`yourdistance <- adist(x = a, y = b, ignore.case = TRUE)`

`yourdistance` will be a matrix calculating the distance between elements.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    3   15    7    7    8
[2,]    7    8    6    7    7
[3,]    7   10    2    3    5
[4,]    7   10    3    2    5
[5,]    8   11    5    5    0
```

For example, the distance between "etytyuli" in a [5,] and "etytyuli" in b [,5] will be 0 because I did not modify that string from a to b.

Once you have this matrix you can decide what is "close enough" for you and select only those elements. You can also play with the parameter cost that allows you to give different cost to insertions, deletions or substitutions.

You might want to learn more about this at:

`https://www.r-bloggers.com/fuzzy-string-matching-a-survival-skill-to-tackle-unstructured-information/`

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's working perfectly, many thanks!! And for the link too, I appreciate it.