# Best method to confront two different vectors containing names of society and find common elements with exact match and quasi similar matches in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, intersect

I'm new to R and I'm trying to work on a project about contacts enrichment from different sources.
*I need to match company names from an excel file* (which is the output of a proprietary CRM) *with Company Names and Email domains from another Company Tool which collects data from a Form and check if there are matches*.

**Goal: Find Which Email Domains are inside the Company Name *exact & quasi similar matches***

So far I have successfully imported both Excel files in R with the `openxlsx` package and imported in 2 different data frame: **Company Names** and **Email Domains Lead**

*Data Frame 1*: **Company Names**

```
| Company Names |
| ------------- |
|BIOLAB S.R.L. |
|BIRRA PERONI S.R.L.|
|CAFFITALY SYSTEM S.P.A.|
|CS 24 SRL |
|A. LOACKER - S.P.A.|
|BAUER S.P.A.|
|BAULI S.P.A.|
|BARRY CALLEBAUT MANUFACTURING ITALIA S.P.A.|
|CARGILL S.R.L.|
```

*Data Frame 2*: **Email Domain Leads**

```
|Email Domain Leads|
| ---------------- |
|formeco|
|esdelgrupposcm|
|a2agencogas|
|prometeoenergy|
|webdomoticas|
|aosp|
|birraperoniindustriale|
|peroni|
|cargill|
|bauli|
```

And what I have already attempted:

I have vectorized the 2 different columns from df1 e df2 in two different variables:

```
company <- unlist(Company_Names)

domain <- unlist(Email_Domains_Lead)
```

to increase the chance of matching I used the function `tolower()`  on both of the vectors and

```
gsub(" ", "", company)
```

on the company vector to make the two vector as similar as possible.

*Then, I tried to find matches with the following methods:*

```
domain %in% company

intersect(domain, company)

which(domain %in% company)
```

Only the `intersect` method did have some success finding 2 matches: **Peroni** and **Cargill** but It did not find **Bauli**

I manually used

```
grep("Bauli", company, value = True)
```

and did find a match, I tried to use `grep` with a vector as pattern but with no success, probably due to my little to no experience, *I was thinking about making a `For` loop with an iteration of every elements of the vector domain as pattern* for the grep function but then I found about

```
agrep()
```

and tried that road with scarce success, but then found out about this

[Find partial matching strings between two vectors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54560105/find-partial-matching-strings-between-two-vectors-in-r)

the function `adist` from the package  `stringdist`

```
 yourdistance <- adist(x = domain, y = company, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

> `yourdistance` will be a matrix calculating the distance between
> elements.
> Once you have this matrix you can decide what is "close enough" for you and >select only those elements.
> You can also play with the parameter cost that allows you to give different >cost to insertions, deletions or substitutions.

**Now I have successfully obtained my matrix with the distances but I am lost on how to use it, if I want to select only the elements with a distance of 3 from the matrix?**

I'm open to suggestions and advices on how to proceed either with

```
adist
```

or the other functions.

Thank you

Comment: The matrix gives you the "level of similarity". The higher the distance the less similar. The example in the referenced post speaks about a value of 0 for an identical match. The row/column position of the distance value gives you the index of the string in one vector to the index of the string in the other vector.

Comment: you can extract the row col indices of a matrix with the which() function setting the array index para to TRUE: try A = matrix(1:12,3,4) and then which(A == 3, arr.ind=TRUE).